# How to implement search functionality in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to develop one application for blackberry in which i want to add one text box on screen.if i enter any word in that text box it should provide me the appropriate result for that search from any particular data(e.g. Contact/any List) so how it be possible?

Comment: check out the BB sample project that comes with jde, keywordfilterdemo application

Comment: sir,in that sample app it searched for those items which are shown on screen already.in my project i want to search those items which are not currently on screen means those items which are shown on screen & the items given for filter are not the same also the source from which to search item is given in form of  collection vector.

Comment: @AmitGaike Seems like Unified search? Be aware it's OS6 and newer. Check out unifiedsearchdemo sample and see [Development Guide - Unified search](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17953/Unified_search_1198034_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Probably `AutoCompleteField` in blackberry will be the best suit for smart search. It is available from BB5.0 and above.  It provides a text field, and filters the data and lists as you entered in the textbox. 
Here is the code sample

```
BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] address = { "T 115 Centro Galleria Shopping Centre, Cnr Old Collier and Walters Road Morley WA 1522", 
                "784 SEAVIEW POINT POINT COOK VIC 2674",
                "Lot 1498 Yarraman Road Wyndham Vale VIC 3795", 
                "784 3506 Witchmount Close Hillside VIC 4055",
                "6 Paas Place Williamstown VIC 4233", 
                "Lot 99 14 James Close Sunbury VIC 4502", 
                "1 Charlotte Street Clayton South VIC 4779" };

        filterList.addDataSet(1, address, "days", BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);

        CustomAutoCompleteTextField autoCompleteField = new CustomAutoCompleteTextField(filterList, AutoCompleteField.LIST_EXPAND_ON_HIGHLIGHT)

        {

            public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
                 ListField _list = getListField();

             }

            //ListField _list = this.getListField();
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){

            }
        };
        add(autoCompleteField);
```